# Database info not showing when previewing site on mobile?

Tags: postgresql, mobile, backend

I have made a simple full stack application that uses a postgreSQL database. When previewing the site on desktop it works fine and is able to retrieve all the information with no problem so long as my backend server is on. I am trying to preview the site on my phone using my IP address followed by the port number and it comes up just fine but only the frontend is displaying on my phone. I am unable to see any information from my backend or database. Does anyone know why that is or how I can fix that to display on my phone (without hosting the site)?

Comment: you didn't provide enough information to help you, mobile usually don't connect directly to a database, you write a REST api on the server wich gather the data from the database and sends them back via html to your mobile. lookup some tutorials about rest and android or iphone and see if you have all steps covered

Answer (score 0):

**1.Maybe it's just cashing issue.
check your mobile phone browser cash setting.**

In general, browsers use caching technology for performance reasons. Caching refers to storing values that you previously requested locally and then reusing old values without using new values when a similar request comes in.

**2.Maybe it's a front-end css problem.**

If design-related elements such as css are not accurate, problems that cannot be seen on the screen may occur even if server data is imported normally.

**3.Or maybe front-end can't get data from the server at all.**

In this case, it is necessary to debug the server source, check whether it is sent normally on the screen, and check whether the response is received normally through the network terminal.

**After checking the three above, even if you can't solve the problem,
At least you'll know exactly what the problem is.**